# Calculate time period using C

Tags: c, time, date

How do I calculate the time period between 2 dates in C (any library, etc.)?

The program should take two (local) dates as input and provide the duration period between them as output.

For example,

```
startDate = OCT-09-1976 and endDate = OCT-09-2008 
should show a duration of 32 years. 

startDate = OCT-09-1976 and endDate = DEC-09-2008 
should show a duration of 32 years and 2 months.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the dates into two struct tm structures with [strptime](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strptime/)

[Difftime](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/difftime/) gives you the difference between the two in seconds.

Convert that into months etc with the code [here](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/post121350-7.html) (in C++, but the only C++ is for the string formatting, easy to change)

EDIT: as a commentor observed, that avoids the month issue. There is (GPL'd) code for
isodiff_from_secs that can be converted to do what you want, if you're happy with its assumption that months have 30 days. See [Google codesearch](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&sa=N&q=isodiff_from_secs+lang:c&ct=rr&cs_r=lang:c) and the description of the standard [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)

Doing the fully-correct solution which takes acccount of the true months between the actual days would be pretty complex. Is that required for your problem?

Comment: Note that the example you link to side-steps the problem of counting months by doing days & years only.

Comment: True. Updated with another link

Comment: I was just curious to see the C version, with the assumption of the correct number of days in the months, etc. I did this thing in Groovy/Java using an excellent Joda time API: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Here's the Groovy/Java code: http://gist.github.com/29050

Comment: I agree with the method. But do note that strptime will work only if the input format is stricly defined. If you want to access more input formats, check the code of GNU date (in GNU coreutils, http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/). You will find a lot of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I did something very similar recently using [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html), and presenting the resulting function as C, but this of course requires using the C++ linker.

Actually, the example leaves a little to be desired - will the start and end dates always be on the same day of the month?  If so you can ignore the day number end up with a trivial subtraction of the month and year numbers.

However if your dates can be anywhere in the month it might be a bit more tricky.  Remember that not all months have the same number of days!

[C difftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/difftime) doesn't help you with month calculations, which is why I used Boost, though you may not have that option.